# When should I use the .As method of Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

When exactly do we need to use the `.As` method provided by Moq?

From the Quickstart documentation:

```
// implementing multiple interfaces in mock
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>();
var disposableFoo = foo.As<IDisposable>();
// now the IFoo mock also implements IDisposable :)
disposableFoo.Setup(df => df.Dispose());
```

But I just don't get why we would want to do that. Could you give me a practical example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, so an example. Let's say you have a transportation management software to manage movement of cars, flights, etc. There are different vehicles but they move on land or air (no sea to simplify the sample).

```
public interface IMovingOnLand
{
    string Move();
}

public interface IMovingInAir
{
    string Move();
}
```

And there is an express transport option for a vehicle/aircraft.

```
public interface IExpressTransport
{
    string MoveDirectly();
}
```

There is a transport manager class which is responsible for moving all the vehicles/aircraft. And it handles express means of transportation bit differently than regular ones (for the sake of simplicity in this sample it only prints a different message depending whether it's IExpressTransport or not):

```
public class TransportManager
{
    public string MoveItem(IMovingInAir airCraft)
    {
        if (airCraft is IExpressTransport)
        {
            return "Message from an express aircraft: " +
                ((IExpressTransport)airCraft).MoveDirectly();
        }
        return "Message from an aircraft: " + airCraft.Move();
    }

    public string MoveItem(IMovingOnLand landVehicle)
    {
        if (landVehicle is IExpressTransport)
        {
            return "Message from an express land vehicle: " +
                landVehicle.Move() +
                ((IExpressTransport)landVehicle).MoveDirectly();
        }
        return "Message from a land vehicle: " + landVehicle.Move();
    }
}
```

Now you would like to test if an airplane behaves differently than a car. And also, if a regular flight is handled differently than an express one. So you test your object as an `IMovingInAir` object and as `IExpressTransport`. To test only flight behaviour you can simply create it as `Mock<IMovingInAir>`. But to *extend* a flight to an express one you have to use `As<IExpressTransport>()` method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestTransportManager()
{
    TransportManager manager = new TransportManager();

    // Create a regular flight.
    var flight = new Mock<IMovingInAir>();
    flight.Setup(x => x.Move())
        .Returns("Air craft moved to next stop.");

    // Create a flight.
    var flightExpress = new Mock<IMovingInAir>();
    // Add standard behaviour.
    flightExpress
        .Setup(x => x.Move())
        .Returns("Air craft moved to next stop.");
    // Extend to express and add express flight behaviour.
    flightExpress
        .As<IExpressTransport>()
        .Setup(x => x.MoveDirectly())
        .Returns("Air craft moved directly to destination.");

    // Get the results.
    var res = manager.MoveItem(flight.Object);
    var resExp = manager.MoveItem(flightExpress.Object);

    // Sssert flight and express fligh returned different messages.
    Assert.AreNotEqual(res, resExp);

    // Assert the expected messages have been returned.
    Assert.AreEqual("Message from an aircraft: Air craft moved to next stop.", res);
    Assert.AreEqual("Message from an express aircraft: Air craft moved directly to destination.", resExp);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the *As* method when you need to test objects that implements **multiple** interfaces.
In [this](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/MoqMultiInterfaces.aspx) sample, the tested code have a specific behavior if the input object implements IDisposable also. Something like this:

```
public void Execute(IFoo input)
{
    // do process...

    IDisposable disposable = input as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

The class implementation:

```
public class ConcreteFoo: IFoo, IDisposable
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**:

The Moq's configuration needed:

```
var foo = new Mock<IFoo>(); 
var disposableFoo = foo.As<IDisposable>(); 
disposableFoo.Setup(df => df.Dispose());

// Verify whether the Dispose() method was called
// That's true only if we use the As method from Moq.
testedClass.Execute(disposableFoo);
disposableFoo.Verify(m => m.Dispose());
```

Comment: that's not Moq's As, thats a c# keyword

Comment: @CRice, to test the "as" C# keyword, you need to use de Moq's "As" generic method.

Comment: Thank You! The link you provided was extremely useful, but I awarded the answer with a more complete example.